# Dynamically checking each KeyValuePair value of a model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I have a view model like so that is created from my validator.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public KeyValuePair<int, RuleType> Foo { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, RuleType> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

My real view model has 20+ field. Once my data is validated a generic list of type `ViewModel` is then returned to my MVC view and processed into a report. However, a feature request has come up where users wish to only see models with errors and warning, excluding valid entities. `RuleType` is a enumerator. A model is valid if all values of the key pair are `RuleType.Success`.

Is it possible to loop through each model and checking the `RuleType` without manually having to check every property? My `GetAllModelsWithErrors()` function would return a list of invalid models. I believe reflection could be a solution however I'm not sure if it's a good solution.

Comment: You can either register all the properties of your ViewModel or use reflection. You can register them for example via the `set` mutator of each property (so you will end up with a collection of `KeyValuePair` instances and you can validate them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private IEnumerable<ViewModel> GetInvalidModels(ViewModel[] viewModels)
    {
        return 
            from viewModel in viewModels 
            from prop in typeof(ViewModel).GetProperties() 
            let ruleType = ((KeyValuePair<object, RuleType>)prop.GetValue(viewModel, null)).Value 
            where ruleType != RuleType.Success 
            select viewModel;
    }
```

Comment: The `let ruleType` line is throwing an invalid exception when I use `ToList()` on my results. Should I be doing something different if some of my KeyValuePair values have nullable types?

Comment: As you said yourself, "A model is valid if all values of the key pair are RuleType.Success". Therefore, my query is based on the assumption that your values in KeyValuePairs are always of RuleType type which is an Enum and thus not nullable.